# Elixir callbacks to promises or async await

Tags: promise, async-await, elixir, synchronous

I have a very long function in elixir that has a callback that looks like the following

```
def outer_fn(param) do
  doing_stuff()
  very_long_sync_function(param, fn (result) ->
    {:ok, short_fn(result)}
  end)
end
```

Where `very_long_sync_function` has a specific return type that is expected in `outer_fn`.  And I was wondering if it was possible to restructure the code in either a javascript-like promise style or ever better an async/await-like style and what it would look like.

Answer (score 2):

I failed to understand from your snippet what exactly are you trying to achieve, but [we have](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#module-async-and-await) [`Task.async/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#async/1) and [`Task.await/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#await/2).

Somewhat along these lines should do:

```rb
def outer_fn(param) do
  t = Task.async(fn ->
    very_long_sync_function(param, fn (result) ->
      {:ok, short_fn(objective_ids)}
    end)
  end)
  doing_stuff()
  Task.await(t)
end
```

[`Task.yield/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#yield/2) allows more grained control over awaiting the result.